# "could not add sta to kernel driver" hostapd - not able to connect more then 10 clients

Tags: 14.04, kernel, iwlwifi, hostapd

I am using an nuc with wifi card "intel 3165" with ubuntu `14.04` amd64 server edition and `kernel version 4.2.0.27` . I have isc-dhcp-server, dnsmasq, hostapd installed and configured on the system .

I soon ran into the problem where I can not connect more than 10 devices . When I try to connect 11th device I get a message in syslog as `could not add sta to kernel driver` .

[kernel wifi](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi)  list says support for  intel 3165 has been added after kernel version 4.1 and so I am using kernel 4.2 , however got stuck with this problem . I am using hostapd v2.1 .

What does this error message exactly means ? Whats the solution to this problem ?

Hostapd.conf-

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=hotspot-1
hw_mode=g
channel=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was the default limit on the card. It supports max 10-12 devices with some tweaking around channel=11 .

To connect more number of devices we need to look in for alternative wireless card .